# « Par nature » a-t-il un sens juridique ?

Tags: sens, expressions, locutions, droit-et-justice

Après avoir lu ce texte :

> Ce sont des biens originellement meubles mais que la loi qualifie d'immeubles par destination en raison du lien qui les unit à un immeuble **par nature** dont ils constituent un accessoire. Ainsi une statue scellée dans une niche ou un tapis d'escalier sont ils des immeubles par destination mais aussi les animaux d'une ferme, les matériels d'exploitation d'un atelier, une cuisine intégrée dans une habitation… Pour qu'un bien meuble puisse être qualifié d'immeuble par destination il faut réunir deux conditions :
>
> 1. le bien immeuble par destination et le bien immeuble par nature auquel il est attaché doivent avoir le même propriétaire,
> 2. le bien immeuble par destination doit être affecté à l'exploitation ou être définitivement attaché à l'immeuble par nature.
>
> <sub>[Source](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=893656)</sub>

j'ai remarqué que « [par destination](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/destination) » possède un sens juridique dans le Larousse. En est-il de même pour « [par nature](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/nature/53894/locution?q=nature#157757) » ?

Le Larousse ne donne que la définition « de façon innée, par tempérament ».
Mais les immeubles ne sont pas innés ni ont un tempérament ?

Le sens de « par nature » se rapproche-t-il de celui de « de nature » ? Y a-t-il une différence ?

Comment: Il y a trois entrées au petit Robert pour *affecter*. Déjà : *par nature* d'un immeuble, renvoie aux notions comptables d'espèces/nature, de mobilier/immobilier ... et de destination/nature comme précisé. S'il était *affecté par* c'est qu'il serait au moins capable d'affection, sinon d'affect, sauf si son affectation a été faire par le notaire. Revoir le questionnement pour discerner la ou lesquelles de ces notions sont interpellées.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le sens que tu cites n'est pas le seul sens de « par nature », ce n'est même pas le sens le plus courant. Le *Larousse* est incomplet, là ; le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nature) est plus complet.

En général, « par nature » est une locution adverbiale (c'est-à-dire une expression qui complète une phrase ou une proposition), et signifie que la proposition concerne les propriétés intrinsèques d'un objet, et non un concours de circonstances.

« De nature » est un synonyme de « par nature », mais la variante « de nature » est [en perte de vitesse](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=par+nature%2Fde+nature%2Cde+nature+%C3%A0%2Fde+nature&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28par%20nature%20/%20de%20nature%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28de%20nature%20%C3%A0%20/%20de%20nature%29%3B%2Cc0). (On retrouve aussi les mots « de nature » dans d'autres expressions comme « de nature à », « état de nature », etc. qui font que les nombres d'occurrences dans les corpus ne sont pas directement comparables.)

> « Toute définition est par nature partielle : elle est restrictive. » (J. Bousquet, *Traduit du silence*, 1936) [= Il est dans la nature d'une définition d'être partielle, parce qu'une définition est intrinsèquement restrictive.]
>
> « Brave autant qu'Achille, la bravoure d'Hector est cependant d'une tout autre qualité. Non bravoure de nature, mais de raison. Courage conquis sur sa propre nature, discipline qu'il s'est imposée. » (A. Bonnard, *De l'Iliade au Parthénon*, 1954) [Achille est brave, tel est son caractère, cela lui vient naturellement. Hector fait preuve de bravoure parce qu'il s'y force.]

En langage juridique, « par nature » est employé comme adjectif ; ce n'est pas le cas dans la vie courante sauf éventuellement en allusion au langage juridique. Le langage juridique distingue les qualifications « par nature » des qualifications « par destination ». La destination est ici le but dans lequel est employé l'objet. Par exemple, une construction avec des fondations, des murs, un toit, etc. est un *immeuble par nature* : son caractère d'immeuble tient à la façon même dont il est construit. En revanche, une caravane n'est pas à priori un immeuble, mais elle peut être un immeuble par destination si on lui retire ses roues, que l'on la relie à une alimentation d'eau, etc. On utilise aussi ces locutions pour qualifier une arme : un fusil est une arme par nature, tandis qu'un couteau de cuisine peut être une arme par destination si l'on s'en sert pour blesser quelqu'un.

Answer (score 1):

Le Larousse est un peu restrictif dans sa définition de *par nature* en utilisant des termes peu applicables aux choses.  Le [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/nature) a l'entrée suivante:

> Par nature, loc. adv. En raison des propriétés de la chose, de l'être dont il est question.

Quant à *de nature*, le Larousse dans le lien cité donne *propre à* tandis que le TFLi donne l'équivalent:

> Être de nature à, loc. verb. Être susceptible d'avoir pour effet de